# Tweaking Emacs Electric Behaviour

Tags: emacs, elisp, whitespace, indentation

I want to override behaviour of electric mode to only make comma electric but not semicolon.

I currently have

```
(defun c-no-hanging-semi ()
  ;; TODO How do I get information about if comma or semicolon was pressed?
  nil)

(add-to-list 'c-hanging-semi&comma-criteria 'c-no-hanging-semi)
```

How do I check in `c-no-hanging-semi` if a comma or semicolon was just pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood the requirement(?), presumably the simplest thing is to stop `;` from calling `c-electric-semi&comma`

```el
(eval-after-load "cc-mode"
  '(define-key c-mode-base-map ";" nil))
```